# Obtain Indices of 1s from a Binary Matrix in a Column fashion

Tags: c, matrix, binary, sparse-matrix, indices

1 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 1

I implemented a program that finds the indices of the number of 1s in a column fashion. For example taking the above binary matrix as an example, the indices that should be obtained are:
0       2       0       1       1       3       0       3       1       2       2       3.

My problem is that to get these indices I had to add two extra rows full of zeros. The fully working program that I implemented is down below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define padding 2
#define rows_Matrix 4  + padding
#define cols_Matrix 6

int main() 
{

   int index = 0;

   //Allocation of Memory for the Binary Matrix. 
   unsigned **Matrix = (unsigned**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned*)*rows_Matrix); //Rows

   for (int i = 0; i < rows_Matrix; i++) //Rows
   {
       Matrix[i] = (unsigned *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * cols_Matrix); //Columns 
   }

   //Assigning elements to the Binary Matrix. 
   Matrix[0][0] = 1; Matrix[0][1] = 1; Matrix[0][2] = 0; Matrix[0][3] = 1;  Matrix[0][4] = 0;  Matrix[0][5] = 0;
   Matrix[1][0] = 0; Matrix[1][1] = 1; Matrix[1][2] = 1; Matrix[1][3] = 0;  Matrix[1][4] = 1;  Matrix[1][5] = 0;
   Matrix[2][0] = 1; Matrix[2][1] = 0; Matrix[2][2] = 0; Matrix[2][3] = 0;  Matrix[2][4] = 1;  Matrix[2][5] = 1;
   Matrix[3][0] = 0; Matrix[3][1] = 0; Matrix[3][2] = 1; Matrix[3][3] = 1; Matrix[3][4] = 0;  Matrix[3][5] = 1;

   //Added padded rows of 0s to get the Matrix a square in order to obtain indices.
   Matrix[4][0] = 0; Matrix[4][1] = 0; Matrix[4][2] = 0; Matrix[4][3] = 0;  Matrix[4][4] = 0;  Matrix[4][5] = 0;
   Matrix[5][0] = 0; Matrix[5][1] = 0; Matrix[5][2] = 0; Matrix[5][3] = 0;  Matrix[5][4] = 0;  Matrix[5][5] = 0;

   //Finding indices of number of 1s in the columns of the matrix.
   printf("Vertical Indices of 1s in the Matrix:\n");

   for (int i = 0; i < rows_Matrix; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols_Matrix; j++)
      {
         if (Matrix[j][i] == 1)
         {
            index = j;
            //Printing indices of 1s in a column fashion.
            printf("%d\t", index); 
         }
      }
   }
   printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program I implemented is as follows:

Vertical Indices of 1s in the Matrix:
0       2       0       1       1       3       0       3       1       2       2       3

I would like to retain the matrix as a 4x6 matrix rather than 6x6 matrix and still obtain the above indices that I got with my program. Is there a way to obtain these indices without the need to add extra padding in C?

Comment: `Matrix[j][i]` should be `Matrix[i][j]` and you can delete the additional lines.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi  The way you recommended will give me the indices of the 1s in a Row fashion. I need to obtain the indices of the 1s in a Column fashion aka in the order:  0 2 0 1 1 3 0 3 1 2 2 3.

Comment: Then switch the two for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows_Matrix; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < cols_Matrix; j++)
```

You need to swap rows and cols like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols_Matrix; i++)  // cols instead of rows
{
   for (int j = 0; j < rows_Matrix; j++)  // rows instead of cols
```

After doing that you can remove the padding

Comment: Thank you :) Just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor defintion

```
#define rows_Matrix 4  + padding
```

should be

```
#define rows_Matrix (4  + padding)
```

If you look at this line

```
unsigned **Matrix = (unsigned**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned*)*rows_Matrix);
```

it expands to

```
unsigned **Matrix = (unsigned**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned*)*4  + padding);
```

This won't behave the same way in

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows_Matrix; i++)
```

where the error is benign.
Always put parentheses around preprocessor statements.